# Ionic 3 File Permissions

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

Alright, here goes. I'm dealing with an ionic project. In this specific scenario we're dealing with testing the Android version of the app. I can get images from the file system just fine, they come back in the form of a string url that looks something like this,

```
content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A5744
```

The processor that is then supposed to blob the file and pass it up the line looks like this:

```
return this.file.readAsArrayBuffer(urlData.url, urlData.fileName)
  .then((item) => {
      return new Blob([new Uint8Array(item)]);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err.message)
  }).then((res)=>{
    return new Blob([res])
  })
```

But then I get the error SECURITY_ERR, which [the documentation](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file) doesn't really talk about.

This works just fine for the pictures I take with the camera, which all have urls that look like this

```
file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<appname>/cache/1502211622334.jpg
```

The issue is, as far as i can find, there is no documentation on what causes this error. I have no idea what to change to make my code work. I have verified the URI is valid, using the checkFile method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So it turns out you can't use content urls with file.readAsArrayBuffer instead you have to first resolve the url into something readAsArrayBuffer can understand. To do this, i used the [ionic native filePath plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-path/).

Once it was installed and included in the page where I needed it, I used the

```
filePath.resolveNativePath(url)
```

method on my url, since this returns a promise, I chained my readAsArrayBuffer onto a then statement prepended to it. I did have to use an if statement to have branching paths for content urls (Which required resolveNativePath) and non-content urls which were already working.

This solution works as far as I can tell.

Comment: thanks for sharing your findings! It partially worked for me, because now I'm getting this error: `Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaDocumentsProvider uri content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document from pid=14113, uid=10260 requires that you obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs`

Comment: You need to enable permissions for that api in the manifest I want to say? Its been like two years since I've touched this stuff, but i remember there being a top level file with permissions that needed editing.

Comment: thanks for the response! I was giving a try at this if someone needs https://stackoverflow.com/a/54788922/5869296, should be the right track