# Permission error when reading file from content uri

Tags: android, react-native

I've been trying to make a simple document picker that allows the user to select a file and returns the selected file encoded in base64.
For that, I'm currently using two packages :

- [react-native-document-picker](https://github.com/Elyx0/react-native-document-picker/tree/v3), which allows the user to pick a file and returns a content uri
- [react-native-fs](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs), for its readFile function that takes an uri in parameter and returns the file in base64

Here is this specific bit of code :

```
    DocumentPicker.pick({
        type: [DocumentPicker.types.allFiles]
    })
    .then(res =>
    {
        RNFS.readFile(decodeURIComponent(res.uri), "base64").then(result =>
        {
            console.log(result)
        })
    })
    .catch(error =>
    {
        console.log(error)
    })
```

It works well when selecting a file from my Downloads folder, however, when I try to select a file from the "Recent" folder or from any folder that isn't related to my app, the readFile fails with the error :

> Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaDocumentsProvider uri content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image:105724 from pid=22663, uid=10471 requires android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS, or grantUriPermission()

From what I've read, MANAGE_DOCUMENTS is a "signature" permission and cannot be added to the manifest.xml or granted by the react native android permission API.

Is there any way I can grant or pass react-native-fs this permission, or any workaround I could use to pick any file without the error ? Am I doing this wrong ?
I've tried using react-native-get-real-path to get a file uri from the content uri and fetching the content uri to get a blob, but it doesn't seem to work.

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answering my question since I found the problem : RNFS.readFile only works when supplied the original res.uri, you don't have to decode it via decodeURIComponent.

The correct code was :

```
RNFS.readFile(res.uri, "base64").then(result =>
{
    console.log(result)
})
```

Comment: I needed decodeURIComponent for iOS so I used it depend on Platform

Answer (score 2):

For anyone stuck on this issue, make sure that you don't use `decodeURIComponent` for Android. But you'll still have to use this for IOS. The following code snippet works on both Platforms

```
import { Platform } from 'react-native';
import DocumentPicker from 'react-native-document-picker';

const file = await DocumentPicker.pick();
const uri = Platform.select({
  android: file.uri,
  ios: decodeURIComponent(file.uri)?.replace?.('file://', ''),
});

const base64File = await RNFS.readFile(uri, "base64");
// Your file handling here
```